# Why can't I redirect output from awk?

Tags: linux, redirection, bash-scripting, awk, pipe

I've written this one liner to show MB read/written every 5 seconds.

```
#!/bin/bash
#iosum.sh
iostat -dmz 5 |\
    awk 'BEGIN{rx=wx=0}{if($0 == ""){printf"%.1f %.1f\n",rx,wx}else if($0~/^Device:/){rx=wx=0}else{rx+=$3;wx+=$4}}'
```

When run from the command line it works perfectly

```
./iosum.sh
# wait
1.1 0.0
0.0 0.1
0.0 0.0
3.0 3.0
0.0 0.0
# ctrl-c
```

However, when I try to put the output into a file I get nothing

```
./iosum.sh > out.txt
# wait
# ctrl-c
cat out.txt
# nothing!
```

What gives?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a buffering issue. [Awk behaves differently](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/I_002fO-Functions.html) depending on whether it is interactive or not. `\n` flushes the output buffer in the latter case only, otherwise, as you experienced, buffering happens until the output buffer is full or is explicitly flushed with the fflush command.

Eventually, there will be something in the output file if you wait for long enough time.

Otherwise, output should be flushed if you kill `iostat`, not the script itself.

Alternatively, here is a simple workaround:

```
script -c iosum.sh out.txt
```

Note that disabling buffering (with `script` or an explicit `fflush`) is affecting performance so killing the `iostat` process (`pkill -f "iostat -dmz 5"`) or setting it to terminate after a given period of time is a better approach if you don't need to monitor the file content, e.g. with a two minute capture period:

```
iostat -dmz 5 120 |\
    awk 'BEGIN{rx=wx=0}{if($0 == ""){printf"%.1f %.1f\n",rx,wx}else if($0~/^Device:/){rx=wx=0}else{rx+=$3;wx+=$4}}'
```

Comment: Indeed it was a buffering issue. I don't know why it was a buffering issue... but adding `fflush(stdout)` after the printf fixed the issue.

Comment: I'm actually piping the output of this script to a status bar, so the output NEEDS to be instant. It only makes one line of output every 5 seconds, is this really affecting performance noticeably?

Comment: No, you are right. A five second rate is making my performance point moot. It would only hurt with a high throughput.

Comment: awk read from a file and redirect output to the same file results into an empty file, is it for the same reason? `awk '{pint tolower($0)}' tmp > tmp`

Comment: @Tiina No, this is unrelated. You are experiencing the shell standard behavior. It starts to set-up the redirections before actually running the command so when `awk` starts, the `tmp` file has already be emptied.

Answer (score 0):

Awk buffers all output and only writes it out when it finishes reading input or when the buffer is full. Use `fflush(stdout)` (see awk man page) in your awk script to make sure the output is properly flushed to disk after every line printed. Like this:

```
iostat -dmz 5 |\
       awk 'BEGIN{rx=wx=0}{if($0 == ""){printf"%.1f %.1f\n",rx,wx;fflush(stdout)}else if($0~/^Device:/){rx=wx=0}else{rx+=$3;wx+=$4}}' > x
```